# Old X11 config for vmware guest

Tags: debian, x11

I wonder if anybody knows X11 configs (for Vmware) which work with ancient linux distros like Debian2:

```
(protocol Version 11, revision 0, vendor release 6300)
Release Date: January 8 2000
        If the server is older than 6-12 months, or if your card is newer
        than the above date, look for a newer version before reporting
        problems.  (see http://www.XFree86.Org/FAQ)
Operating System: Linux 2.2.14-va.4.4-i586 i686 [ELF] 
Configured drivers:
   FBDev: Server for frame buffer device
   (Patchlevel 11): mfb, cfb8, cfb16, cfb24, cfb32
```

These distros didn't have the Vmware SVGA driver yet. Just Vesa, fbdev and alikes. From these I'm not sure which one is the best choice for vmware.

Complete X configs would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Oh good lord, why?!?

Comment: It is likely that vmtools will not work for these old releases.

Comment: You can go for VESA, this has most chance to work

Answer (score 0):

I made partially work but the screen looks terrible and the mouse using `/dev/psaux` is stuck in the top of the screen.

## XF86Config:

```
# The Colour SVGA server

Section "Screen"
    Driver      "svga"
    #Device      "Generic VGA"
    Device      "My Video Card"
    Monitor     "My Monitor"
    Subsection "Display"
        Depth       8
        # Omit the Modes line for the "Generic VGA" device
        Modes       "640x480" "800x600" "1024x768"
        ViewPort    0 0
        # Use Virtual 320 200 for Generic VGA
    EndSubsection
    Subsection "Display"
        Depth       16
        Modes       "640x480" "800x600" "1024x768"
        ViewPort    0 0
    EndSubsection
    Subsection "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes       "640x480" "800x600" "1024x768"
        ViewPort    0 0
    EndSubsection
    Subsection "Display"
        Depth       32
        Modes       "640x400" "800x600" "1024x768"
        ViewPort    0 0
    EndSubsection
EndSection
```

## StartX log:

```
XFree86 Version 3.3.6 / X Window System
(protocol Version 11, revision 0, vendor release 6300)
Release Date: January 8 2000
    If the server is older than 6-12 months, or if your card is newer
    than the above date, look for a newer version before reporting
    problems.  (see http://www.XFree86.Org/FAQ)
Operating System: Linux 2.2.14-va.4.4-i586 i686 [ELF] 
Configured drivers:
  SVGA: server for SVGA graphics adaptors (Patchlevel 1):
      NV1, STG2000, RIVA 128, RIVA TNT, RIVA TNT2, RIVA ULTRA TNT2,
      RIVA VANTA, RIVA ULTRA VANTA, RIVA INTEGRATED, GeForce 256,
      GeForce DDR, Quadro, ET4000, ET4000W32, ET4000W32i, ET4000W32i_rev_b,
      ET4000W32i_rev_c, ET4000W32p, ET4000W32p_rev_a, ET4000W32p_rev_b,
      ET4000W32p_rev_c, ET4000W32p_rev_d, ET6000, ET6100, et3000, pvga1,
      wd90c00, wd90c10, wd90c30, wd90c24, wd90c31, wd90c33, gvga, r128, ati,
      sis86c201, sis86c202, sis86c205, sis86c215, sis86c225, sis5597,
      sis5598, sis6326, sis530, sis620, sis300, sis630, sis540, tvga8200lx,
      tvga8800cs, tvga8900b, tvga8900c, tvga8900cl, tvga8900d, tvga9000,
      tvga9000i, tvga9100b, tvga9200cxr, tgui9400cxi, tgui9420, tgui9420dgi,
      tgui9430dgi, tgui9440agi, cyber9320, tgui9660, tgui9680, tgui9682,
      tgui9685, cyber9382, cyber9385, cyber9388, cyber9397, cyber9520,
      cyber9525, 3dimage975, 3dimage985, cyber9397dvd, blade3d, cyberblade,
      clgd5420, clgd5422, clgd5424, clgd5426, clgd5428, clgd5429, clgd5430,
      clgd5434, clgd5436, clgd5446, clgd5480, clgd5462, clgd5464, clgd5465,
      clgd6205, clgd6215, clgd6225, clgd6235, clgd7541, clgd7542, clgd7543,
      clgd7548, clgd7555, clgd7556, ncr77c22, ncr77c22e, cpq_avga, mga2064w,
      mga1064sg, mga2164w, mga2164w AGP, mgag200, mgag100, mgag400, oti067,
      oti077, oti087, oti037c, al2101, ali2228, ali2301, ali2302, ali2308,
      ali2401, cl6410, cl6412, cl6420, cl6440, video7, ark1000vl, ark1000pv,
      ark2000pv, ark2000mt, mx, realtek, s3_savage, s3_virge, AP6422, AT24,
      AT3D, s3_svga, NM2070, NM2090, NM2093, NM2097, NM2160, NM2200,
      ct65520, ct65525, ct65530, ct65535, ct65540, ct65545, ct65546,
      ct65548, ct65550, ct65554, ct65555, ct68554, ct69000, ct64200,
      ct64300, mediagx, V1000, V2100, V2200, p9100, spc8110, i740, i740_pci,
      i810, i810-dc100, i810e, Voodoo Banshee, Voodoo3, smi, generic
(using VT number 7)

XF86Config: /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/XF86Config
(**) stands for supplied, (--) stands for probed/default values
(**) XKB: keymap: "xfree86(us)" (overrides other XKB settings)
(**) Mouse: type: Intellimouse, device: /dev/psaux, baudrate: 1200
(**) Mouse: buttons: 3
(**) SVGA: Graphics device ID: "My Video Card"
(**) SVGA: Monitor ID: "My Monitor"
(--) SVGA: Mode "640x400" needs vert refresh rate of 69.93 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "800x600" needs vert refresh rate of 56.25 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1024x768" needs vert refresh rate of 86.96 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "640x400" needs vert refresh rate of 85.08 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "640x480" needs vert refresh rate of 69.98 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "640x480" needs vert refresh rate of 75.00 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "800x600" needs vert refresh rate of 60.32 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "640x480" needs vert refresh rate of 85.01 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1152x864" needs vert refresh rate of 89.18 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "800x600" needs vert refresh rate of 72.19 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "640x480" needs vert refresh rate of 100.02 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "800x600" needs vert refresh rate of 84.99 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1024x768" needs vert refresh rate of 70.07 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1280x1024" needs vert refresh rate of 87.59 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "800x600" needs vert refresh rate of 100.03 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1024x768" needs vert refresh rate of 75.94 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1152x864" needs vert refresh rate of 69.74 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1280x1024" needs vert refresh rate of 60.96 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1024x768" needs hsync freq of 70.24 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1152x864" needs hsync freq of 70.88 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1280x1024" needs hsync freq of 74.59 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1600x1200" needs hsync freq of 75.00 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1152x864" needs hsync freq of 76.01 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1280x1024" needs hsync freq of 78.86 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1024x768" needs hsync freq of 80.21 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1280x1024" needs hsync freq of 81.13 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1600x1200" needs hsync freq of 87.50 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1152x864" needs hsync freq of 89.62 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1280x1024" needs hsync freq of 91.15 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1600x1200" needs hsync freq of 93.75 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1600x1200" needs hsync freq of 105.77 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1280x1024" needs hsync freq of 107.16 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1800X1440" needs hsync freq of 96.15 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "1800X1440" needs hsync freq of 104.52 kHz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "512x384" needs vert refresh rate of 77.97 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "512x384" needs vert refresh rate of 85.09 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "320x200" needs vert refresh rate of 69.93 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "320x240" needs vert refresh rate of 75.14 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "400x300" needs vert refresh rate of 56.34 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "400x300" needs vert refresh rate of 60.32 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "400x300" needs vert refresh rate of 72.19 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "480x300" needs vert refresh rate of 56.34 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "480x300" needs vert refresh rate of 60.19 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "480x300" needs vert refresh rate of 62.99 Hz. Deleted.
(--) SVGA: Mode "480x300" needs vert refresh rate of 72.07 Hz. Deleted.
(**) FontPath set to "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/:unscaled,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/:unscaled,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/,/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/"
(--) SVGA: PCI: Unknown vendor (0x15ad) Unknown chipset (0x0405) rev 0, Memory @ 0xd0000000, 0xc8800000, I/O @ 0x10f0
(--) SVGA: chipset:  generic
(--) SVGA: videoram: 64k
(--) SVGA: clocks:  25.18
(**) SVGA: Using 8 bpp, Depth 8, Color weight: 666
(--) SVGA: Using builtin driver modes
(--) SVGA: Builtin Mode: 320x200
(--) SVGA: Virtual resolution set to 320x204
(--) SVGA: SpeedUp code selection modified because virtualX != 1024
System: `/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/xkb/xkbcomp -w 1 -R/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/xkb -xkm -m us -em1 "The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:" -emp "> " -eml "Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server" keymap/xfree86 /var/tmp/xfree86.xkm'
Warning: /dev/psaux unable to get status of mouse fd (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
xinit:  connection to X server lost.

waiting for X server to shut down
```

[image]